# Would replacing a resistor by another one of identical value but higher power rating affect the working of a circuit?

Tags: resistors, power-dissipation

The schematic recommends using 20 Ω 1W as collector resistance.
What I have at hand are two 10 Ω rated for 10W. I'm guessing the change should be acceptable ...

What difference would it make if i were to use these two instead of that whose rating is specified?

Comment: The circuit might need adjusting DC-offset if it is in en existing circuit. Usually easy to recognize by a trimpot nearby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than overkill (or possible tolerance differences), two 10ohms in series (@10W) would be fine as a replacement-- there would only be possible cause for concern if they were underrated
(<1/2W ea).

Answer (score 6):

In many cases the change would be acceptable.

**Inductance:** In instances where high frequency AC is being dealt with it is reasonably possible that the higher power resistors are wire wound. If special care is not taken to produce a non-inductive resistor a wire wound resistor tends to have inductance due to the spiral of wire that it is made from. This can produce significant effects in some cases - but this is unlikely to be a problem in the vast majority of circuits. Where low to no inductance is required, wire can be doubled and wound onto a former so that current flows from input to halfway point with one rotation and from halfway to end with the other rotation - this cancelling out inductance overall. This places constraints on construction methods and insulation and would be avoided if not needed.

**Voltage rating:** For 20 Ohm resistors it will not be a problem, but resistors have voltage ratings and in a high voltage circuit (hundreds of Volts) you need to be sure that a replacement or replacements handle the voltage properly. Generally replacing one resistor with two will make voltage problems less severe.

**"Precision":** As Pat noted - if the original resistor was high 'accuracy' (say +/-1% tolerance ) and needed the precision, replacing with low precision high tolerance resistors may cause problems. It is not uncommon for power resistors to be +/- 10% rated wheras a 1 Watt resistor is liable to be 5% and maybe 1%.